# PHP not working on certain File

Tags: server, apache2, php

I have recently gotten into PHP. I have PHP and Apache2 installed on my Ubuntu computer. The server is working, and so is PHP. However, I can only get my "test.php" file to work properly. I have another file called "phpinfo.php" but it does not work. Both files have the same exact code.

```
    <?php
    phpinfo();
    ?>
```

Why would only one file be working? And how can I fix this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Both files in the same directory?And in which way is the other not working? Any error messages?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same directory. "test.php" produces everything that phpinfo produces. "phpinfo.php" which is the same code as the other document, produces a blank white page.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the apache config files located in

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/

and if you have just installed it, the file would be named as

> default

.

Ensure that the config file is pointing to the correct folder and your scripts are located there.